Novel, possibly by Walter de la Mare, where protagonist is descended from the Green Girl
Long ago I read a brief mention of a novel where the protagonist was a man descended through many centuries from the medieval Green Girl of Woolpit.
And I have an idea for a story where a future Earthman travels to the world that the Green Children came from and becomes involved in the affairs of the green people there.  And he might as well be descended from the Green Girl, and if so he should be descended either from any present day person who might claim to be descended from the Green Girl, or from that fictional novel character descended from the Green Girl.
I think I remember reading that the novel with a protagonist descended from the Green Girl was by Walter de la Mare (1873-1956). a
So can anyone identify that novel where the protagonist was descended from the Green Girl?

While writing my question I thought that it didn't had enough clues to make it worthwhile for someone to try finding the novel, and so I decided the find the book where I read a mention of that novel.
And as it happened, I remembered some lines from a fairy poem by Horace Walpole (1717-1797) giving the title of King Oberon of the Fairies "Oberon the Grand, Emperor of Fairyland, King of Moonshine, Prince of Dreams...". And I thought that probably came from the same book about fairies in literature that also mentioned the novel I wanted.
So I tried googling for  "Oberon the Grand, Emperor of Fairyland" and selecting books as the field to search.  And I found The Fairies in English Tradition and Literature by Katherine Mary Briggs, 1967 at the Internet Archive.
https://archive.org/details/fairiesinenglish0000kath/page/205/mode/1up
Since I thought that the novel I remembered reading about was by Walter de la Mare, I searched the index for him and found a discussion of his fairy prose on pages 204-205.  And page 205 also mentioned the novel I remembered, but by someone else.
The Moon is Feminine by Clemence Dane (1937) real name Winnifred Ashton.
It is available at the Internet Archive:
https://archive.org/details/bwb_O8-CZG-177
And as it turned out I didn't have to bother anyone else and was able to find it in just a few minutes of internet searching.  But I thought that some people might interested in a novel that sounds so strange.
